# Sending Form URL in the mail link using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, web-config

I have a requirement where I want to send the User the link of the form via **Email**. The link for every user will be different. Currently I am just passing hardcode value in the mail.

Here is my code.

```
sb.AppendLine("Please click on the link to view the details.");
            sb.AppendLine("</br></br>");
            sb.AppendLine("<a href='" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClickHereLink"].ToString() + "' >Click here to open request</a>. ");
            sb.AppendLine("</br></br>");
            sb.AppendLine("<b>This is a system generated mail. Please do not reply to the sender.</b>");
```

And the `ClickHereLink` is been defined in `Web.config` like below

```
<add key="ClickHereLink" value="https://www.test.com"/>
```

How can I send dynamic link for every user based on the details

**Encryption Method**

```
public static class EncryptDecrypt
{
    public static string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }
    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you are sending the actual \ dynamic link, where will that data be coming from

Comment: @CodeWarrior: from my application. here is one sample link. `http://localhost:22306/Sitesurvey.aspx?SapId=y%2b9mq5VMohUuShOnxWVTD%2bqzCpyoS4ddvIU6y3nIpZZv2Vo%2bUR2717IPuo3nnJY8&CandidateId=xl3H6vEYPqCWuI2dvaeboA%3d%3d&Type=yHl5KZQ6w7Xar02zj7L3%2fUCHcBaXZ5iUK3DVbIABsak%3d`

Comment: ok, that doesnt answer my question, how is the link generated and where from?

Comment: it's generated from web.config. and I have refere it in my `SendMail` function

Comment: but you state that the link will be different each time? so I assume that your main htt[://www.blah.com is coming from the web config and everything else after that will be different?

Comment: yes you are right. so how would I handle this part.?

Comment: the first part I need to know is how are you going to generate this? is it coming from a database, is it a query string, is it encoded there are still too many unknowns for me at the moment to help you

Comment: @CodeWarrior: yes its encoded with query string.

Comment: ok, and is that the query string that is present at the time of sending the email?

Comment: Also, whats the encryption method?

Comment: @CodeWarrior: updated the code for your reference.

Comment: OK, leave it with me and i'll sort something for you

Comment: @CodeWarrior: sure. waiting for your answer. Also let me know if you need anything from me

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using .Net 4.x, and if so Try this,

if you are not using 4.x then where I have used string interoperlation then you should change that for string.Format("...", ...);

```
    void Main()
{
    var urlStr = new StringBuilder();
    var url = "http://www.yoursite.com";
    urlStr.Append($"{url}?{BuildQs(Request.QueryString)}");

}

private string BuildQs(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection collection)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var key in collection.Keys)
    {
        var value = collection[key.ToString()].ToString();
        sb.Append($"{key}={value}");

    }
    var enc = new EncryptDecrypt();
    return enc.Encrypt(sb.ToString());
}

public class EncryptDecrypt
{
    public string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }
    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
}
```

Comment: how should I do it in asp.net. its c# purely

Comment: Where I have used main() you should take that code, drop it above your string builder, drop my other method in somewhere that you can get to in your code and then that should work charm

Comment: i m not getting it. still confused how to implement your answer.

Comment: lets go into a chat room later, i cant really talk it through at the moment

Comment: i will be free after 1900BST

Comment: sure.. just ping me here so that we can chat and finish it of

Comment: Hey, really sorry I forgot to come back online the other day... did you get this sorted?